# A problem when solving an equation with symbolic variables

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, physics, symbols

I asked a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262345/solving-equations-with-symbolic-variables/262346#262346) a couple days ago and received a solution that worked for me at the time. But now I am seeing that the proposed solution fails for some other cases I need.

For example, if I just have one equation (instead of three as in the [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262345/solving-equations-with-symbolic-variables/262346#262346))

```
eq1 = (a[3] - a[4]) \[Psi] . \[Xi] + (a[1] + 2 a[2]) \[Psi] . \[Phi];
var = Variables[Level[{eq1}, {-1}]]

(* {\[Xi], \[Phi], \[Psi]} *)

sol = Select[Solve[{eq1} == 0], 
  FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ var] &]

(* {} *)
```

The solution should be `a[3]=a[4]` and `a[1]=-2a[2]`, because `\[Psi] . \[Xi]` and `\[Psi] . \[Phi]` are different and can be treated as independent variables. How can I make the code work for this case also?

P.s.: One can define `var={\[Psi] . \[Xi],\[Psi] . \[Phi]}`, because, as I said, I treat them as independent variables.

Comment: `Solve[((List @@ eq1) /. _Dot :> 1) == 0][[1]]`

Answer (score 3):

What about `SolveAlways?

```
var = {\[Psi] . \[Xi], \[Psi] . \[Phi]}
SolveAlways[eq1 == 0, var]
(*{{a[1] -> -2 a[2], a[3] -> a[4]}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol[eq_] := Solve[Cases[eq1,
     c_ *_Dot :> c, Infinity] == 0];

eq1 = (a[3] - a[4]) ψ . ξ + (a[1] + 2 a[2]) ψ . ϕ;

sol[eq1]

(* {{a[2] -> -(a[1]/2), a[4] -> a[3]}} *)
```

For the original problem,

```
eqns = {
   (a[3] - a[4]) ψ . ξ + (a[1] + 2 a[2]) ψ . ϕ, 
   2 (a[3] - a[4]) ψ . ξ, 
   (a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4]) ψ . ϕ};
```

Solving separately,

```
sol /@ eqns

(* {{{a[2] -> -(a[1]/2), a[4] -> a[3]}}, {{a[2] -> -(a[1]/2), 
   a[4] -> a[3]}}, {{a[2] -> -(a[1]/2), a[4] -> a[3]}}} *)
```

Solving as a system,

```
sol@eqns

(* {{a[2] -> -(a[1]/2), a[4] -> a[3]}} *)
```